# Python get field type of mongo collection

Tags: python, types, field, pymongo

I am trying to get the mongodb data type and field name from pymongo and I don't see any api or anything that could do so. I do manage to get the field name through the index_information but it does not show the data type.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps, you could use a `type` function in pytho to get the data type

Comment: @hahkalpesh hmm, it becomes a dictionary, but the screenshot shows the mongodb table.